# Scraping HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am working on a project in which I need to crawl several websites and gather different kinds of information from them. Information like text, links, images, etc.

I am using Python for this. I have tried BeautifulSoup for this purpose on the  HTML pages and it works, but I am stuck when parsing sites which contains a lot of JavaScript, as most of the information on these files is stored in the `<script>` tag.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: and another ressource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624255/how-to-scrape-search-results-if-returned-in-javascript-using-python/22630026#22630026

Comment: as a side note, selenium is much more lighweight than Ghost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, scrapping and parsing JS from pages is not trivial. It can however be vastly simplified if you use a headless web client instead, which will parse everything for you just like a regular browser would.
The only difference is that its main interface is not GUI/HMI but an API.

For example, you can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) with Chrome or Firefox which both support headless mode.

For a more complete list of headless browsers check [here](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/3694955).

Comment: i am able to get ghost work and load the page but what should i do get whole webpage out of it. the documentation describes a function get_page but it is not there even in the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a lot of javascript dynamic load involved in the page loading, things get more complicated.

Basically, you have 3 ways to crawl the data from the website:

- using browser developer tools see what [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests are going on a page load. Then simulate these requests in your crawler. You will probably need the help of [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) modules.
- use tools that utilizes real browsers like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). In this case you don't care how the page is loaded - you'll get what a real user see. Note: you can use a [headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions) browser too.
- see if the website provides an API (e.g. [walmart API](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/))

Also take a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) web-scraping framework - it doesn't handle AJAX calls too, but this is really the best tool in web-scraping world I've ever worked with.

Also see these resources:

- [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)
- [Scraping javascript-generated data using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052465/scraping-javascript-generated-data-using-python)
- [web scraping dynamic content with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608572/web-scraping-dynamic-content-with-python)
- [How to use Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python)
- [Headless Selenium Testing with Python and PhantomJS](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.Uzl9wq1dXQg)
- [selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started with selenium and BeautifulSoup:

Install phantomjs with npm (Node Package Manager):

```
apt-get install nodejs
npm install phantomjs
```

install selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

and get the resulted page like this, and parse it with beautifulSoup as usual:

```
from BeautifulSoup4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
client = webdriver.PhantomJS()
client.get("http://foo")
soup = bs(client.page_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very fast way would be to iterate through all the tags and get `textContent`
This is the JS snippet:

```
page =""; var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (tag of all) page = page + tag.textContent;
```

or in selenium/python:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://ranprieur.com")
pagetext = driver.execute_script('page =""; var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (tag of all) page = page + tag.textContent; return page;')
```

[image]